# PHP code not running in eclipse. Printed out but not executed

Tags: java, php, mysql, eclipse, servlets

I am using eclipse kepler to code. I use java servlet and MySQL to store data (part of the requirement of the assignment). I have issue with add.php file that i created to insert data into the DB using JavaScript that directs it to servlet. I also have the PHP code on the page which displays the data that is in the database. The problem is, the PHP codes are being displayed but not executed. If i run it through http://localhost/e-RMS/WebContent/add.php, the PHP will execute but the servlet will not execute(not adding the data to DB). It goes the other way around. If i use http://localhost:8080/e-RMS/add.php (from eclipse with Apache tomcat v7 running) it will run the servlet but only prints out the PHP code without executing it. I have installed PHP PDT with interpreters set to version 5.4 and still not working.

Code of add.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Add table</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbname = 'resto';
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql="SELECT table_No, pax_No FROM reserve";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result ->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "tableNo.: ".$row["table_No"]. " paxNo.: " .$row["pax_No"]."    <br>" ;
}
} else {
    echo "no result";
}

$conn->close();
?>

<form method="post" action="add">
    <label for="studentName">Table No.</label>
    <input type="text" id="tableNo" name="tableNo"/>
    <br/>
    <label for="studentID">pax amount:</label>
    <input type="text" id="paxNo" name="paxNo"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please Note that i am not allowed to use PHP to insert my data. I have to use servlet. Is it possible to retrieve the data from my DB using Jscript?

Edit: INSERT Statement is in the servlet

```
//connect to DB
    Connection conn = null;
    String db = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/resto";
    String db_driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String user = "root";
    String pass = "";

    try {
            Class.forName(db_driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db, user, pass);
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into reserve(table_No, pax_No) values(?,?)");

            stmt.setInt(1, tableNo);
            stmt.setInt(2, paxNo);

            stmt.executeUpdate();



    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: `action="add"` that should be `action="add.php"` - right now, PHP is interpreting that as `action="add/index.php"` you could also do `action=""` which is the same as "self". Also use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php for the query.

Comment: However, I don't know why you're using a form without POST arrays and you mention to insert data. *"not adding the data to DB"* - there's no `INSERT` here, so your question is unclear.

Comment: "add" is the servlet(in this case called addHandler.java). By changing it to add.php, no data will be added to DB. SQLs will be handled in addHandler. not in the PHP. the sole purpose of it being a php file is to read and display the values that is on the DB.

Comment: well I don't see an `INSERT INTO` in your question, so the problem may lie in there. Again, check for errors on your DB and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and on the PHP side http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - your posted code doesn't support the question.

Comment: As i have stated before, SQL statements are handled in different file. It is working until I created the php for viewing purpose. Again, there is no problem in my SQL statements. I am required to use servlet to pass the value to DB. Therefore, having an INSERT INTO statement in the add.php file is not an option.

Comment: So, you are saying that they allowed you to create a database connection and use the database, just told you not to use any INSERT/UPDATE statements? That's a very strange security policy. Anyway, is your servlet running on port 8080 or on port 80?

Comment: INSERT statement is at the "add" servlet not on php

Comment: I have added the code for insert statement